# Why use .success() with getJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For the jQuery function, what is the reason to use .success()?  The initial function will execute upon success right?  So aren't you just executing twice when you include .success()?

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
//this will execute upon success
})
.success(function() { 
  //doesn't this do what the above is doing?
 })
```

Comment: FYI, `success()` method is deprecated

Comment: I dont think i've seen it done, have you seen this somewhere? it might be that it was used in error/misunderstanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If looking it in isolation and just the happy scenario, yes: they do the same thing. The callback as the final argument of `$.getJSON` gets called regardless of the result of the request.

The `.success()` way of doing it is inspired by Promises. You can read more about them here: https://promisesaplus.com

Promises set a better interface for composing many asynchronous operations as well as handling the non-successfull scenarios.

You should use `.then()` instead of `.success()`: https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Comment: The getJSON API reference (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) also points to .done(), .fail(), .always() but for JSONP.  I'm not using JSONP.  But the above methods still work.  Is it a problem if I use them anyway with getJSON()?  They don't mention .then() by the way.

Comment: getJSON returns a deferred, and it supports .then(): https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/, however .done() and .fail() fit perfectly too!

Answer (score 3):

They were designed to have one function executed in each case. A success case, an error case, and a general function that always executes.

But as [stated here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), `.success()` is deprecated. See:

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Using this approach, you have one function to execute in case of success, another to execute in case of failure, and a final one to execute in whichever case:

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqXHR object for this request
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
    .done(function() {
        alert( "success" );
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
    })
    .always(function() {
        alert( "complete" );
    });

// Perform other work here ...
// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.always(function() {
alert( "second complete" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the success function in this case, you are already defining a function to be executed on success.

Answer (score 0):

You can see when your request is succesfull.You can see a message in console and things like that...i don't know